# loop in __init__ function?

Tags: python, class, init

I am wondering if it is okay in style perspective to include for loop in `__init__` function of a class.

Given a list of integers I am trying to generate `another_list` that stores differences in current value and next value. However I would like to use `another_list` for more than one method within the class. So I was thinking about creating another_list in `__init__` function rather than converting it for every method. Is this the most simplest way? what is the conventional style?

Answer (score 2):

Well it is not a bad practice to use a loop but I will refactor the loop in another function to keep things tidy

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, some_list):
        self.this_list = some_list
        self.create_another_list()

    def create_another_list(self):
        self.another_list = self.this_list[::-1]

    def print_another_list(self):
        return self.another_list

A([1,2,3]).print_another_list()
```

You can create a loop in `__init__` as well

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, some_list):
        self.this_list = some_list
        self.another_list = self.this_list[::-1]

    def print_another_list(self):
        return self.another_list
A([1,2,3]).print_another_list()
```

Design wise both are correct

Answer (score 0):

There's no limits on what you must or should write in `__init__`. Loops is no different. If you think that you need to calculate instance attribute via loop – go for it.

Everything that is part of object state [logically] should be saved as attribute, there's no reason to re-compute it, if it is *not* a dynamic argument for other methods. This is kinda basic idea behind the OOP that python follows.

Comment: Thanks! I was just curious if that is the conventional style.

Comment: No widespread convention against it. You can even write loops in class body )